# Populating table using 2 different *ngFor

Tags: angular, html-table, ngfor

Below is my array of JSON objects:

```ts
{
  "tagFrequency": [
    {
      "value": "aenean",
      "count": 1,
      "tagId": 251
    },
    {
      "value": "At",
      "count": 1,
      "tagId": 249
    },
    {
      "value": "faucibus",
      "count": 1,
      "tagId": 251
    },
    {
      "value": "ipsum",
      "count": 1,
      "tagId": 251
    },
    {
      "value": "lobortis",
      "count": 1,
      "tagId": 194
    },
    {
      "value": "molestie",
      "count": 1,
      "tagId": 251
    },
    {
      "value": "unde tempor, interdum ut orci metus vel morbi lorem. Et arcu sed wisi urna sit egestas fringilla, at erat. Dolor nunc.",
      "count": 1,
      "tagId": 199
    },
    {
      "value": "Vestibulum",
      "count": 1,
      "tagId": 251
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to display these attributes viz. value, count and tagName(which is taken using tagId) in a table. For first two attributes I am using ngFor. But, I want to also print tagName which I am getting using tagId and storing it in tagNames array. Following is my component code:

```ts
frequencies: any;
tagNames: string[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    if (this.route.snapshot.url[0].path === 'tag-frequency') {
      let topicId = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

      this.tagService.getTagFrequency(topicId)
        .then(
            (response: any) => {
          this.frequencies = response.json().tagFrequency
          for(let tagFrequency of this.frequencies) {
            this.getTagName(tagFrequency.tagId)
          }
        }
        )
        .catch(
            (error: any) => console.error(error)
        )
    }
}

  getTagName(tagId: number): string {
    return this.tagService.getTag(tagId)
    .then(
        (response: any) => {
          this.tagNames.push(response.name)
        }
    )
    .catch(
      (error: any) => {
        console.error(error)
      }
    )
  }
```

And this is how I am trying to print them on UI:

```ts
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ 'word' }}</th>
      <th>{{ 'tag-name' }}</th>
      <th>{{ 'frequency' }}</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let name of tagNames">
        <tr *ngFor="let frequency of frequencies; let i=index">
          <td>{{ frequency.value }}</td>
          <td>{{ name }}</td>
          <td>{{ frequency.count }}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But I am getting [object object] under the column tag-name. Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

I tried using ng-container as above, but result looks like this on UI:
[image: tag-name-issue]

Which is wrong. I need only first 3 rows with a tag-names as "Subtag 3", "Zeit1", "Tag 1" for rows 1,2,3 respectively.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: update the post with the json data which makes easy for others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use index variable, iterate over frequencies array in *ngFor and use its index for tagNames

```
<tr *ngFor="let frequency of frequencies; let i=index">
      <td>{{ frequency.value }}</td>
      <td>{{ tagNames[i] }}</td>
      <td>{{ frequency.count }}</td>
  </tr>
```

Make sure you have initialized tagNames:

tagNames: string[] = [];

Answer (score 4):

You can't have double `*ngFor` on a single element. You can use the helper element `<ng-container>` like

```
  <tr *ngFor="let frequency of frequencies; let i=index">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let name of tagNames">
      <td>{{ frequency.value }}</td>
      <td>{{ name }}</td>
      <td>{{ frequency.count }}</td>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I am sorry. Its not working for multiple elements. E.g. If I have total 8 rows then those 3 attributes are populating 8 times on single row. I simply want to print this as 8 x 3 matrix.

Comment: I guess you only need to remove the `<ng-container>` element, or move it outside the `<tr>`

Comment: What do u mean by removing <ng-container>?? If I move it outside <tr>, 64 rows are coming that means its repeating 8 times. I want only 8 rows. Somehow I dont want nesting of for loops.

Comment: I don't know what you want.

Comment: In a table, two columns viz. value and count are populating from object Frequency while name is populating from an array tagNames. I want to print them simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out from that explanation what you mean. Can you put the expected HTML result to your question?

Comment: I will provide a snapshot of both what I want and what is currently rendering